# MySQL Schema Change Management Tools?

Tags: mysql, schema

*I am a developer who has worked with SQL Server by way of Entity Framework, I am now using MySQL by way of Node.js*

I am stepping into your strange world to ask an operations question I hope you can help me with. I imagine this is pretty basic for many of you DBAs. *I am not 100% sure what terms I should be searching for with this.*

What tools exists where I can make schema changes to a Development database as I see fit, then at any time I can **compare** the present state of Development database to the present state of Production database.

For Example

Production vs Development

Now that tool will generate a diff SQL file that simple makes all of the Alters.

Thus

```
 -  OriginalSchema.sql
 -  001.update.sql
 -  002.update.sql
 -  003...
```

Finally, does a tool exists that can not only generate said scripts but can also manage the UP (patch) and DOWN (rollback) of running said scripts.

```
~$ tool compare local remote
~$ tool generate local remote
~$ tool apply remote latest 
~$ tool rollback --steps=2
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Check out Liquibase

Answer (score 0):

It's called **Schema migrations** and one of hundreds of tools that can manage that is [migrate](https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate) written in GO.

> Database migrations written in Go. Use as CLI or import as library.

I never heard that any of those schema migration tools can do a diff between dev and prd.